# How do I print a star pyramid pattern using recursion without any loop in C?

Tags: c, function, recursion, printf

I do this but it's using a `for` loop. I don't want it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printPattern(int n);

int main()
{
    int n = 4;  
    printPattern(n);
    return 0;
}

void printPattern(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
       printf("*\n");
       return;
    }

    printPattern(n - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < (2 * n - 1); i++)
    {
        printf("* ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This is the output:

```
*
* * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * * * *
```

I don't want any loop in my code like a `for` loop, a `do`/`while` loop or a `while` loop.

Comment: Be aware that the `design-patterns` tag is not the appropriate tage to be used for questions about drawing pyramides and similar stuff.

Comment: You can create a recursive `printRow(int n)` function to print a single row, and use it from your `printPattern` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this:

```
for(int i=0;i< (2*n-1);i++)
{
    printf("* ");
}
```

by calling this function (not tested):

```
void print_asterisk(int amount)
{
  if (amount == 0)
  return;
  else
  {
    print ("**");
    print_asterisk(amount - 1);
  }
}
```

Like this, you have replaced your for-loop by a recursive call.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"* * "` rather than `"**"`?

Answer (score -3):

The assignment is not easy for beginners like you and me.

But we, beginners, should help each other.

I can suggest the following solution shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printPattern( int n )
{
    if (n < 0)
    {
        printf( "* " );
        printPattern( n + 1 );
    }
    else if (n == 0)
    {
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    else
    {
        if (n > 1)
        {
            printPattern( n - 1 );
        }
        printPattern( -2 * n + 1 );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
    {
        printPattern( n + 1 );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
*

*
* * *

*
* * *
* * * * *

*
* * *
* * * * *
* * * * * * *

*
* * *
* * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *

*
* * *
* * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * *

*
* * *
* * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * *

*
* * *
* * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

*
* * *
* * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

*
* * *
* * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

Another approach is to write two recursive functions. The first one will call itself for the number of rows in the pyramid and other will be recursively called to output a row. However in this case you will have two functions instead of one recursive function.

Comment: @Jack There is a loop in main to demonstrate calling the function for different values of n.

Comment: but you are using for loop also.....

Comment: @ViharRamavat The for loop used in main to demontrate calling the function for different "heights" of the pyramid. You may call the function for any height you like. For example instead of the for loop in main you may just write  printPattern( 4 ); The function itself contains neither loop.

Comment: I don't see the point solving people's assignment.

Comment: @panic I solve my assignments. It is an interesting assignment for me and I have tried to resolve it. Otherwise there is nothing to do at SO.:)

Comment: @panic And I am glad that my answers solve people's assignments. :) It seems you do not understand yourself what you are saying because it follows from your comment that other answers do not solve people's assignments.:) It means that my  answer is the best answer.:) Good luck!:)